# routerLinkActive is not working when queryParams is binded to a property defined as getter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

In my component controller I have a property -

```
 public get navigationParams() {
    return {
      fromDate: sessionStorage.getItem('fromDate'),
      toDate: sessionStorage.getItem('toDate')
    };
  }
```

Note: I need it in session storage so that I can redirect from other pages where it is not part url state.

```
<div class="card" routerLinkActive="active"
             [routerLink]="['/dashboard/revenue']"
             [queryParams]="navigationParams">
 Revenue
</div>
```

It should apply active class which it is applying for the first time but as date changes through datepicker(ng2-bootstrap) it updates `fromDate` and `toDate` in sessionStorage reloads nested state-
`this.router.navigate([], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams: this.navigationParams)` and the now the style is gone.

However it works if I use a property like
`public queryParams: any;` instead of `navigationParams`

```
<div class="card" routerLinkActive="active"
             [routerLink]="['/dashboard/revenue']"
             [queryParams]="queryParams">
 Revenue
</div>
```